# How do I calculate the number of items I can purchase given a percent discount?

Tags: percentages

Given a certain amount of money, m, and a percentage discount, d, how do I calculate the number of items, i, that I can purchase?

Is it simply $i = {m \over 1-d}$?

Comment: It depends on the price of the item.

Comment: Yes, right. I think my formula is calculating how much my money is worth at a given discount.

Comment: it doesn't matter about the price as it is reduced consistently

Comment: So, given price, p, I think the correct formula would be $i = {m \over p(1-d)}$

Comment: I think that looks ok.

Comment: Cool. Thanks for the help.